# How to get original request URL in shiro

Tags: shiro

I use `org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter` and it redirects to `login.jsp` as per configuration `authc.loginUrl = /login.jsp` in my `shiro.ini`

How to get the original request URL in the `login.jsp`

PS:
Say my url was `localhost:8080/myApp/i.html` now it redirects to `login.jsp`

I have ExtJs app for login and after successful authentication i want to redirect back to `i.html` the URL user actually requested for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WebUtils class of shiro to get original request like this

```
WebUtils.getAndClearSavedRequest(request)
```